# canvas and pattern fabric.js and perspective.js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Currently I am working on tile vitualizer project in which the user can upload their own image and select the floor area and apply any tiles on their wish to have a look of their room based on tile and bought it. I have created pattern using selected tile image and create path on canvas and apply fill style to have a look but it is not feel like a floor.

What I am getting is 
[image: result image]

So, I tried perspective.js to get some realistic result.

I can make the tile repeated image looks like floor using points but we have some transparent space in canvas while applying the canvas as pattern it missed some floor space because of being transparent.

Result using perspective.js
[image: result image using perspective.js]

How to overcome this problem? Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perspective.js is a badly named library as it does not do perspective at all, rather it does a type of skew distort. Perspective requires the size of pixel to change in relation to the distance from the viewer. The canvas 2D API is not capable of this type of transform (unless you use a scanline or raytrace  renderer). You will need to use webGL. Something like Three.js or there are some webGL filter libraries that have perspective transforms as part of the filter set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I will try it on Three.js

Comment: Do you have any similar examples?

Comment: I need to create floor in image as 3d and make that as pattern to fill in the paths.